# How to design a flow which can control other independent flows without building child-parent relation

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-flow

How can we in MS flow control the execution of other flows?
To be more specific:
How can we do the followings in a flow:

```
1 -Check the status of other flows? e,g, running, idle
2- If they are running, for how long they are running?
3- Turn the other flows on or off?
4-a bit greedy, but can we check the value of a variable in other flows if they are in a running state? (e.g. Can we check the variable 'var_a' of flow B which is in the running state while we are in flow A (no child-parent relation between these flows)?
```